# retrieving username with signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-authentication

i manage my users with the Firebase Admin SDK.
On signup i send email,password and username to my endpoint.
i createUserWithEmailAndPassword and create a doc in my firestore

This way i can check if a document already exists and return an error that the username/handle is already taken.

```
Firestore
  - users
    - handle
      * email
      * userId (from createUserWithAndPassword Response)
      * createdAt
```

After the user signInWithEmailandPassword i only have the token, email and userId.. but i need the handle to get the right user details.

what i get from the docs is that there is a default displayName property but i dont know how to set it on signup.

or should i create a custom Token and store the handle inside of it..

im not sure how to go from here

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple method for what you want:

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    // Sign in success
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName(mName).build();

                    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
             }
         }
     });


                }
    });
```

Then, to retrieve it, use this wherever required:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address etc
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
}
```

There are multiple ways, but I recommend to use this one :)